# extension Fast/Quick Order view in each category

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, product-list

I use module Fast/Quick Order and I want to do fast order in each category. I tried copy code from qickorder.phtml to list.phtml but I get message "There are no products matching the selection."

Comment: For an easy solution, if you can purchase this extension [Quick Order](https://www.mageants.com/wholesale-fast-order-for-magento-2.html), You can restrict the extension features to a specific customer group and there are other features as well.